# Flutter Crashing on Run: flutterBuildDebugandroid-arm:compile

Tags: flutter

**Flutter (1.6.1-pre.80) Crashing on Run**

We had a production application running smoothly, but upon upgrading to the latest flutter, we are receiving the following:

```
The task name: 'flutterBuildDebugandroid-arm:compile' must not contain any of the following characters: [/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |]
```

We ran `flutter clean` but this didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

I spent one and a half day to resolve this issue, it was exactly display a an error as same as your. Then I finally downgraded to Flutter 1.6.0 and clear all cache then it worked.

Hope this help.